# Good inductive logic programming system

Tags: prolog, inductive-logic-programming, progol

Can you recommend a inductive logic programming system? Preferably one that uses Prolog syntax. Are there systems that do predicate invention and learning recursive rules? I am somewhat familiar with Aleph and Prolog. What is the state of the art?

Tanks! JCR

Comment: I heard once about *Golem* which is an ILP system, and if I recall the textbook correctly, it was indeed "prolog-like" style. https://www.revolvy.com/page/Golem-%28ILP%29 But unfortunately I can not find much on the Internet, or at least not a good manual (instantly).

Comment: Logtalk includes a port of Metagol, an ILP system, that you can run with most Prolog systems: https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/ports/metagol

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly a request for a recommendation, which is not an appropriate inquiry for Stack Overflow.

Comment: PROBABLY YOU TOLD ABOUT ALEPH AND **PROGOL**